# value of the integral $\int_0^{2\pi} \log|1-ae^{i \theta}| $

Tags: complex-analysis, self-learning

This is a problem from Complex Analysis by Stein and  Shakarchi.

We have to find the the value of  $\int_0^{2\pi}  \log|1-ae^{i \theta}| $ when $|a|<1$. So I tried to solve it in this manner.

I first made the substitution $e^{i\theta}=z$.   Then the integral becomes $\int_\gamma  \frac{\log|1-az|}{iz} $. Then we observe that $\int_0^{2\pi}  \log|1-ae^{i \theta}| $ is the real part of the integral $\int_0^{2\pi}  \log(1-ae^{i \theta}) $. So we will evaluate $\int_\gamma  \frac{\log(1-az)}{iz} $. But this function has a removable singularity at $z=0$.So the integral of this function is zero since it is holomorphic. So its real part is also zero.

Is my reasoning right?If not can someone please point out what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: @5xum: What's wrong? $\ln(z) = \ln(|z|) + \arg(z) i$. So if the original integral exists, we can split it into the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @5xum i also had the same argument as user21820 in mind

Comment: My bad, I withdraw my comment...

Comment: Anyway you should always write the $dθ$ or $dz$ to make clear what you're integrating with respect to. You can use "\,dz" in LaTeX to have the extra spacing.

Comment: I would concur that it is zero from integrating (the real part of) $$\ln  \left( 1-a{{\rm e}^{i\theta}} \right) =-\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{
\frac {{a}^{n}{{\rm e}^{i\theta\,n}}}{n}}$$

Comment: @Graham Hesketh thanks you i actually was not sure we could do that because it looks like adding infinitely many holomorphic which i did not know would be holomorphic

Comment: @happymath: You can differentiate or integrate any convergent Taylor series and the result has the same radius of convergence. This is not a trivial fact and should of course be proven at some point in your book.

Comment: @user21820 thank you can you please tell where I used it apart from it is my proof correct.

Comment: @happymath: You didn't use it at all because you simply noted that it is a removable singularity, and then you used Cauchy-Goursat theorem to get the integral being $0$.

Comment: @GrahamHesketh: Sorry I take back my comment; your infinite series is not a Taylor series in Θ and so integrating it with respect to θ requires some justification like proving that the series is absolutely convergent, if I didn't miss anything.

Comment: Well, I don't think it has to converge absolutely but in this case it does for $|a|<1$ it converges faster than a geometric series.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Instead of appealing to removability of a singularity, you could use Cauchy's integral formula to the same effect: if $f$ is holomorphic on the closed unit disk (meaning it's holomorphic in some larger open set), then
$$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i } \int_{|z|=1}\frac{f(z)}{z-0}\,dz = \frac{1}{2\pi   } \int_{|z|=1}f(z)\,|dz| $$
Using $f(z)= \log(1-az)$ and taking real part of both sides yields the claim.

The Related sidebar contains a number of other questions about this integral.